# My Widget id's are showing an error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So i was doing a project for a color clicker. I typed in the ids into a listOf Array, and the ID was showing an error.

MainActivity

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setListeners()

    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text,
            box_four_text, box_five_text)

        for (item in clickableViews) {
            item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it) }
        }
    }



    private fun makeColored(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {

            // Boxes using Color class colors for background
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

            // Boxes using Android color resources for background
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)

            // Boxes using custom colors for background
            R.id.red_button -> box_three_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_red)
            R.id.yellow_button -> box_four_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_yellow)
            R.id.green_button -> box_five_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_green)

            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }
}
```

bulid.gradel(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.examples.colormyviews"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" android:id="@+id/constraint_layout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/box_one"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:id="@+id/box_one_text"
            style="@style/WhiteBox"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/box_two"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130sp" android:id="@+id/box_two_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_one_text" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" style="@style/WhiteBox"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/box_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_three_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box_two_text"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_four_text"
            style="@style/WhiteBox"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/box_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_four_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_three_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_five_text" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" style="@style/WhiteBox"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/box_five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_five_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_four_text" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text" style="@style/WhiteBox"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/how_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="24sp" android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/tap_directions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.081"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.606"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/red_button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/red_button"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/green_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/green_button"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/green_button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/green_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/red_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yellow_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/yellow_button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/green_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/green_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the id's are in the setListener fun but it doesn't work. This has happened to me on other projects, but I still haven't found the solution to this issue. If anyone has any suggestions, that'll be great.

Comment: I didn't know synthetic was depreciated. They removed it completely.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find out how to do it. Apparently, you have to add it to your project since Android Studio took it out.

First add this plugin UNDER the plugin section and BEFORE the Android section in your bulid.gradle (app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then add this import to your Main Activity or other places you want to use it

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

That's all you need and it should work as intended.

Comment: this is what you _can_ do, but you probably shouldn't, because it's deprecated